# Adding Link Around DIV Breaks Bootstrap 4 Carousel

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and utilizing the Carousel component with WordPress. It worked great but I wanted to add a link around the image. When I do this, the carousel ceases to slide.

(Note: I opted to replace the carousel indicators with text links, which works the same.)

The link I add works for the first slide and will take me to the URL, but it does not auto slide nor responds to clicks on the links that should be triggering the slide. I've commented the code to highlight problem areas. Help is appreciated.

Wrapping the  that contains the background-image with  tag is causing the carousel to no longer move to the next slide. I want the  with the background image clickable, but of course I also want the carousel to move onto the next slide when prompted.

```
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">

  <div class="carousel-inner"> 
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

     <!-- Adding the below <a> tag causes the issue -->
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><div style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0] ?>') no-repeat; background-size:cover;" class="carousel-item <?php if ( $the_query->current_post == 0 ) : ?>active<?php endif; ?>">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
          <p class="d-none d-sm-block"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div><!-- END CAPTION -->
      </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
    </div><!-- END CAROUSEL ITEM --></a> <!-- End attempt at linking image -->
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
  </div><!-- END CAROUSEL INNER -->

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row slider-row carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">
        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 feature-box highlight carousel1">

        <!-- The <a> tag below stops working -->
            <a data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $the_query->current_post; ?>" class="carousel-link <?php if ( $the_query->current_post == 0 ) : ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        </div><!-- END COL -->
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
      </div><!-- END ROW -->
    </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
</div> <!-- END MY CAROUSEL -->
```

Comment: what are you want to say ? explain in brief, what you need and what's your problem !

Comment: You didn't close the a tag, need to add </a> at the end

Comment: He ended it after `<!-- END CAROUSEL ITEM --></a>` @bhmahler

Comment: For the second part you should start a new query, and give `wp_reset_postdata();` for the first query, it may or may not related to issue but its a good practice.

Comment: Unless you are using html5, the a tag only supports inline elements, which a div is not.  Your post does not show your doctype and is not tagged with an html version so not sure if this applies.

Comment: @bhmahler I am using HTML5 and the <a> wrapped around the <div> does indeed work. The issue is the carousel will no longer move to the next slide. It seems unrelated but if I remove the wrapping <a> tag around the <div> the carousel does function as expected.

Comment: @NishargShah I added another few sentences to clarify the end goal in case my original explanation was unclear.